# AWS Firewall Terraform: How to add managed stateful rule groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My terraform code provisions AWS network firewall, rule group and policies. I would like to add the AWS managed stateful rule groups of `AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder`,
`MalwareDomainsStrictOrder`, `BotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder` and `AbusedLegitMalwareDomainsStrictOrder` etc. The sample code as follows provisions firewall rule group and policies.

```
# Default actions: DROP_ALL & ALERT_ALL
resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "anfw_policy" {
  name = "firewall-policy-${var.identifier}"
  firewall_policy {

    # Stateless configuration
    stateless_default_actions          = ["aws:forward_to_sfe"]
    stateless_fragment_default_actions = ["aws:forward_to_sfe"]
    stateless_rule_group_reference {
      priority     = 10
      resource_arn = aws_networkfirewall_rule_group.drop_remote.arn
    }

    # Stateful configuration
    stateful_engine_options {
      rule_order = "STRICT_ORDER"
    }
    stateful_default_actions = ["aws:drop_strict", "aws:alert_strict"]
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      priority     = 10
      resource_arn = aws_networkfirewall_rule_group.allow_icmp.arn
    }
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      priority     = 20
      resource_arn = aws_networkfirewall_rule_group.allow_domains.arn
    }
  }
}

# Stateless Rule Group - Dropping any SSH or RDP connection
resource "aws_networkfirewall_rule_group" "drop_remote" {
  capacity = 2
  name     = "drop-remote-${var.identifier}"
  type     = "STATELESS"
  rule_group {
    rules_source {
      stateless_rules_and_custom_actions {

        stateless_rule {
          priority = 1
          rule_definition {
            actions = ["aws:drop"]
            match_attributes {
              protocols = [6]
              source {
                address_definition = "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
              source_port {
                from_port = 22
                to_port   = 22
              }
              destination {
                address_definition = "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
              destination_port {
                from_port = 22
                to_port   = 22
              }
            }
          }
        }

        stateless_rule {
          priority = 2
          rule_definition {
            actions = ["aws:drop"]
            match_attributes {
              protocols = [27]
              source {
                address_definition = "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
              destination {
                address_definition = "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# Stateful Rule Group 1 - Allowing and logging ICMP traffic
# As it uses Strict Rule Ordering, first the "alert" rule is going to log the packet before it is passed.
resource "aws_networkfirewall_rule_group" "allow_icmp" {
  capacity = 100
  name     = "allow-icmp-${var.identifier}"
  type     = "STATEFUL"
  rule_group {
    rules_source {
      rules_string = <<EOF
      alert icmp any any -> any any (msg: "Allowing ICMP packets"; sid:1; rev:1;)
      pass icmp any any -> any any (msg: "Allowing ICMP packets"; sid:2; rev:1;)
      EOF
    }
    stateful_rule_options {
      rule_order = "STRICT_ORDER"
    }
  }
}

# Stateful Rule Group 2 - Allowing access to .example.com (HTTP) and .amazon.com (HTTPS)
# As it uses Strict Rule Ordering, first the "alert" rule is going to log the packet before it is passed.
resource "aws_networkfirewall_rule_group" "allow_domains" {
  capacity = 100
  name     = "allow-domains-${var.identifier}"
  type     = "STATEFUL"

  rule_group {
    rule_variables {
      port_sets {
        key = "HTTP_PORTS"
        port_set {
          definition = ["443", "80"]
        }
      }
    }

    rules_source {
      rules_string = <<EOF
      alert http $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET 80 (http.host; dotprefix; content:".example.com"; endswith; msg:"Allowing example.com HTTP requests"; sid:892120; rev:1;)
      pass http $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET 80 (http.host; dotprefix; content:".example.com"; endswith; msg:"Allowing example.com HTTP requests"; sid:892121; rev:1;)
      alert tcp $HOME_NET any <> $EXTERNAL_NET 80 (msg:"Allowing TCP in port 80"; flow:not_established; sid:892122; rev:1;)
      pass tcp $HOME_NET any <> $EXTERNAL_NET 80 (msg:"Allowing TCP in port 80"; flow:not_established; sid:892123; rev:1;)
      alert tls $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (tls.sni; dotprefix; content:".amazon.com"; endswith; msg:"Allowing .amazon.com HTTPS requests"; sid:892124; rev:1;)
      pass tls $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (tls.sni; dotprefix; content:".amazon.com"; endswith; msg:"Allowing .amazon.com HTTPS requests"; sid:892125; rev:1;)
      alert tcp $HOME_NET any <> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"Allowing TCP in port 443"; flow:not_established; sid:892126; rev:1;)
      pass tcp $HOME_NET any <> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"Allowing TCP in port 443"; flow:not_established; sid:892127; rev:1;)
      EOF
    }
    stateful_rule_options {
      rule_order = "STRICT_ORDER"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to replace the "Stateful Rule Group 2" with the AWS managed stateful rule groups I mentioned above. How to do it?

Using stateful_rule_group_reference works! Line 26 works perfectly. I would like to use the variables for the ARN. I got errors (line 27). Any solutions of using varialbes?

```
 24     stateful_rule_group_reference {
 25       priority     = 21
 26       #resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:${var.region}:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControl    DomainsStrictOrder"
 27       resource_arn = join("/", [data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup, "AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"])
 28     }
```

```
data "aws_arn" "stateful-rulegroup" {
  arn =  "arn:aws:network-firewall:${var.region}:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup"
}
```

```
│   on fw_policy.tf line 27, in resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "anfw_policy":
│   27:       resource_arn = join("/", [data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup, "AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling join(separator, lists...)
│     │ data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup is object with 7 attributes
│
│ Invalid value for "lists" parameter: element 0: string required.
```

Comment: I think you might need another `stateful_rule_group_reference` in the `aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy` resource where you would reference ARNs of the managed policies, if you can find them somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is first listing the AWS managed network rule groups using AWS CLI command:

```
aws network-firewall list-rule-groups --scope MANAGED
```

You can find the ARN of each of the rule groups you want in the output. Then, you can just reference the ARN in the `aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy` resource (shortened for :

```
resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "anfw_policy" {
  name = "firewall-policy-${var.identifier}"
  firewall_policy {
    .
    .
    .
    # Stateful configuration
    stateful_engine_options {
      rule_order = "STRICT_ORDER"
    }
    stateful_default_actions = ["aws:drop_strict", "aws:alert_strict"]
    stateful_rule_group_reference {
      priority     = 10 # set the priority
      resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:<region>:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"
    }
  }
}
```

You could use a variable and assign it values of the ARNs for the AWS managed stateful rule groups so you don't have to hard-code them, which would also allow for some prettier code to be written. The priority would of course had to be adjusted to your needs.

Comment: Using stateful_rule_group_reference works! Thank you very much! Line 26 works perfectly. I would like to use the variables for the ARN. I got errors (line 27). Any solutions of using varialbes?  Note: I posted new code above.

Comment: That's a different question to the OP. If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it and asking a new question.